# Check and create iterative directories

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm creating an image upload function in CodeIgniter 2.1.4 that saves the images in iterative folders based on the order of upload.

For example, the first batch will look at the directory `images/`. If the directory contains no **folders**, it creates one called `1`. The second batch will check the same directory, recognize that the folder `1` exists and create a new folder called `2`.

In other words, the function will always create a new folder with the name `i+1`, where `i` is the number of current folders.

How would I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a directory in php using the function mkdir. You can read about it in the [php docs](http://php.net/mkdir).
There is also a function called is_dir, which will check to see if a directory with that name exists already. You should be able to figure out the rest =]

Answer (score 0):

You can do as bellow:

```
$root = "Path_to_root_folder";
$n = 5;
for($i=1;$i<=n;$i++)
{
   if (!is_dir($root."/".$i)) {
    mkdir($root."/".$i);         
   }
   else
   {
      // continue with your code
   }
}
```